# arcgis js API 4.7 error in Internet Explorer- "no native wasm support detected"

Tags: angular, webassembly, esri-javascript-api, esri-loader

Im using ArcGIS JS API 4.7, in an angular 6 application.

and using esri-loader to access esri methods within my angular services/components

Using following versions..

```
"arcgis-js-api": "^4.7.2",
"bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"esri-loader": "^2.3.0",
"esri-service": "^1.1.1",
```

It seems esri has implemented part of the of the js methods in webassembly.
hence the browsers  use following files

```
https://js.arcgis.com/4.7/esri/geometry/support/pe-wasm.js
https://js.arcgis.com/4.7/esri/geometry/support/pe-wasm.wasm
```

This is specifically used in
JsonUtils.fromJson() method

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-support-jsonUtils.html#fromJSON

The code seems to run fine in other browsers, however I get errors in all versions of IE, including Edge

tested in
IE  11.2791.12

Edge 38.14393.2068.0

Following is my code

```
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

...
...

public static async createGeometry(
    geometryJson: any
  ): Promise<__esri.Geometry> {
    const [JsonUtils] = await loadModules([
      'esri/geometry/support/jsonUtils'
    ]);
    return JsonUtils.fromJSON(geometryJson);
  }
```

Following is the error

```
no native wasm support detected
ERROR abort("no binaryen method succeeded. consider enabling more options, like interpreting, if you want that: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/WebAssembly#binaryen-methods"). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

[object Error]{description: "no binaryen...", message: "no binaryen...", name: "Error", stack: "Error: no b...", Symbol(rxSubscriber)_g.byk0skaafg7: undefined}
```

Has anyone faced it in the past?

Comment: The API requirements - specifically the IE11 limitations - are listed in more details in https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/system-requirements/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is expected.

It uses WebAssembly and IE never will be able to support WebAssembly. For Edge, you should update [Windows 10 Fall Creators Update](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/10/31/optimizations-webassembly-sharedarraybuffer-atomics-edgehtml-16/#gt8Prpx087tC1cS6.97). Specifically, EdgeHTML(*NOT* Edge) version 16 supports WebAssembly.